# how to route 2 Nics with 2 public IP on same subnet running with same gateway

Tags: linux, routes, gateway, subnet, nic

I'm newbie in networking field. I have trouble with my web server Network configuration (OS is Centos).
I have 2 NICs (eth0 + eth2 - physically) running 2 public IP which have the same subnet, same gateway.
When I configure nginx to listen on these 2 NICs, everything works just fine. But when I monitor the traffic, all traffic is on the eth0 only, nothing on eth2.
My question is: How can I configure so that traffic goes in a NIC, go out on that NIC, too?
This is my ethernet card config:

```
DEVICE="eth0"
ONBOOT=yes
BOOTPROTO=static
IPADDR=x.x.x.38
PREFIX=27
GATEWAY=x.x.x.x.33
DNS1=8.8.8.8
DNS2=8.8.4.4
NAME="System eth0"

DEVICE="eth2"
ONBOOT=yes
BOOTPROTO=static
IPADDR=x.x.x.39
PREFIX=27
GATEWAY=x.x.x.33
DNS1=8.8.8.8
DNS2=8.8.4.4
NAME="System eth2"
```

This is my route -n result

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
10.14.8.0       0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth1
y.z.0.0         0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1002   0        0 eth0
y.z.0.0         0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1003   0        0 eth1
y.z.0.0         0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1004   0        0 eth2
0.0.0.0         x.x.x.33        0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
```

Hope you can help, thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 1):

In Linux, routing is performed by looking at the destination address only, so a packet will follow whichever route can be used to reach the packet's destination, with no regard to the source address.

The behaviour you want requires choosing a route depending not only on the destination address, but also on the source address — this is sometimes called *source-sensitive routing* or *SADR* (source-address dependent routing).  The most portable way of implementing source-sensitive routing under Linux is to define routing rules across multiple routing tables using the `ip rule` and `ip route ... table ...` commands.

This is described in detail in Section 4 of the [Linux Advanced Routing and Traffic Control HOWTO](http://www.lartc.org)

Comment: I found this article, this is exactly what I need. http://multipath-tcp.org/pmwiki.php/Users/ConfigureRouting

Answer (score 0):

Probably, the problem can be solved even with NAT.
ip tuntap add dev tap0 mode tap
ip tuntap add dev tap1 mode tap
Then you can assign separate ip addresses to these devices:
ifconfig tap0 10.10.10.1 netmask 255.255.255.255
ifconfig tap1 10.10.10.2 netmask 255.255.255.255
And finally - redirect incoming traffic to specific virtual device
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.10.10.1
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth2 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.10.10.2
In this case, all traffic will be routed definetely to the interface it came from.